# Making a dynamic query from node to a mySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm

I'm trying to pass through a dynamic value from node using the mysql npm package. I'm pretty sure there's a syntactical error, but for the life of me cannot get the query to function properly.

Here is the function that calls the query:

```
function checkInventory() {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE item_id = ?'),[productID],
    function (error, results) {
      if (error) throw err;
      console.log(results);
    }
}
```

The database connection has been established, I read the data earlier in the program. However I keep getting an error saying the mySQL syntax is incorrect. When I run the query from workbench, it works fine. How can I pass through my `productID` variable into the query?

Comment: What value does `productID` have and what is the error message?

Comment: @Mohrn productID is an integer, I ran a console.log to double check. The error message is `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1`

Comment: @Mohrn also tried stringifying `productID`, same error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the brackets. Try this

```
function checkInventory() {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE item_id = ?', [productID],
    function (error, results) {
        if (error) throw err;
        console.log(results);
    })
}
```